# Red5 server installer is empty at localhost/installer?

Tags: red5

[image]I am installing red5 media server. It installed successfully, but when i click to install it shows empty list of demos like the figure attached.How to add demos by adding directly in folder?

Answer (score 0):

Are you having internet connection ? If yes, then you can directly download them. If no, then try [these](https://github.com/mondain/red5/tree/master/snapshots) *.war files. Put them in webapps directory of your red5 server.(*I haven't tried the 2nd method*)